# Decimal data type not storing the values correctly in both spark and Hive

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, spark-csv

I am having a problem storing with the decimal data type and not sure if it is a bug or I am doing something wrong

The data in the file looks like this

```
Column1 column2 column3
steve   100     100.23
ronald  500     20.369
maria   600     19.23
```

when I  infer the schema in the spark using the csv reader its taking the data type of column3 as string ,So I am converting it in to decimal and saving it as table.

Now when I access the table it is showing the output in the following way eliminating the decimals

```
Column1 column2 column3
steve   100     100
ronald  500     20
maria   600     19
```

I also tested the same thing in Hive by creating a local table with column3 as decimal and loaded it with the data and again the same thing it is not storing them as decimal.

Any help in this regard would be appreciated.

Here is the code for the above one

In spark The schema of the file

```
root
 |-- DEST_AIRPORT_ID: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- DEST_AIRPORT_SEQ_ID: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- DEST_CITY_MARKET_ID: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- DEST string: string (nullable = true)
 |-- DEST_CITY_NAME: string (nullable = true)
 |-- DEST_STATE_ABR: string (nullable = true)
 |-- DEST_STATE_FIPS: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- DEST_STATE_NM: string (nullable = true)
 |-- DEST_WAC: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- DEST_Miles: double (nullable = true)
```

Code

```py
from pyspark import SparkContext
sc =SparkContext()

from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)

Data=sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").options(header="true").options(delimiter=",").options(inferSchema="true").load("s3://testbucket/Data_test.csv")

Data1=Data.withColumnRenamed('DEST string','DEST_string')

Data2 =Data1.withColumn('DEST_Miles',Data1.DEST_Miles.cast('Decimal'))

Data2.saveAsTable('Testing_data', mode='overwrite',path='s3://bucketname/Testing_data')
```

Schema after converting in to decimal

```
root
 |-- DEST_AIRPORT_ID: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- DEST_AIRPORT_SEQ_ID: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- DEST_CITY_MARKET_ID: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- DEST string: string (nullable = true)
 |-- DEST_CITY_NAME: string (nullable = true)
 |-- DEST_STATE_ABR: string (nullable = true)
 |-- DEST_STATE_FIPS: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- DEST_STATE_NM: string (nullable = true)
 |-- DEST_WAC: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- DEST_Miles: decimal (nullable = true)
```

For the Hive

```sql
create table Destination(
        DEST_AIRPORT_ID int,
        DEST_AIRPORT_SEQ_ID int,
        DEST_CITY_MARKET_ID int,
        DEST string,
        DEST_CITY_NAME string,
        DEST_STATE_ABR string,
        DEST_STATE_FIPS string,
        DEST_STATE_NM string,
        DEST_WAC int,
        DEST_Miles Decimal(10,0)
      );
INSERT INTO TEST_DATA SELECT * FROM TESTING_data;
```

Let me know if you still need more information.

Thanks
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`DECIMAL` in Hive V0.12 meant "a large floating point". Just like NUMBER(38) in Oracle.

But in later versions there has been a major change and `DECIMAL` **without any specification of scale/precision** now means "a large integer". Just like a NUMBER(10,0) in Oracle.

*Reference*

- [Hive language manual / data types](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types#LanguageManualTypes-DecimalTypeIncompatibilitiesbetweenHive0.12.0and0.13.0)
- a lengthy PDF document labeld "Hive Decimal Precision/Scale Support" somewhere in cwiki.apache.org

Bottom line: you have to **explicitly** define **how many digits** you want, which is exactly what the ANSI SQL standard expected decades ago. For instance, `DECIMAL(15,3)` will accomodate 12 digits in the integer part + 3 digits in the decimal part *(i.e. 15 digits w/ a comma in a arbitrary position)*.

Comment: Precision of 15 means the entire number can have only 15 digits total (both integer and fractional parts). "As of Hive 0.13 users can specify scale and precision when creating tables with the DECIMAL datatype using a DECIMAL(precision, scale) syntax.  If scale is not specified, it defaults to 0 (no fractional digits). If no precision is specified, it defaults to 10." https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types#LanguageManualTypes-DecimalsdecimalDecimals

Answer (score 1):

Both Spark and Hive have a default precision of 10 and scale of zero for Decimal type. Which means if you do not specify the scale, there will be no numbers after the decimal point.

Answer (score 0):

The file has different delimiter (I think tab) & you are reading the file with ','.

Yes, it converts to String, but you shouldn't lose data. Try this:

```
>>> lines = spark.read.options( delimiter='\t', header='true').csv("/home/kiran/km/km_hadoop/data/data_tab_sep")
>>> lines.show()
+-------+-------+-------+
|Column1|column2|column3|
+-------+-------+-------+
|  steve|    100| 100.23|
| ronald|    500| 20.369|
|  maria|    600|  19.23|
+-------+-------+-------+

>>> lines.printSchema()
root
 |-- Column1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- column2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- column3: string (nullable = true)
```

You can convert to DoubleType like below. 
(Note: for your case, you don't need it because you are writing to FS)

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.types import DoubleType
>>> lines.select(lines["column1"], lines["column2"], lines["column3"].cast(DoubleType())).printSchema()
root
 |-- column1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- column2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- column3: double (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue while reading a data from oracle and I can able to fix this with casting

```
joinedDF.col("START_EPOCH_TIME").cast("string")
```